# How videos in Instagram starts to play automatically and count its views? How to achieve this feature in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am currently building an Instagram clone app using Flutter and Firebase Firestore.

I wanted to know how videos in Instagram starts to play automatically when we scroll up to them, and how can I achieve this in my app.

And also wanted to count the number of views I get on each post (both for photo or a video post).
It seem to be difficult to count no. of views for photo posts as user won't be doing any change in a event which we can consider as a count. 
[ In Instagram if a video is played for >3sec then its counted as one view ]

So can anyone help me by giving idea to do this in flutter ?

Answer (score 0):

In flutter repository issue about this feature is [opened.](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26767)
May be this [solution](https://github.com/rvamsikrishna/inview_notifier_list/blob/master/README.m) gives you some idea how to release it.